# WEBrick rails server verbosity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick, verbose

Is there a way to start the WEBrick server with no verbosity. I feel like it logs too much information. For example:

```
rails s --verbose=false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the log level in your Rails configuration.

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels